# Separating text from image in a document

Tags: c#

I want to build something that works as follows:

- Read a jpg file
- See if there is an actual image (like the image of a person) within this jpg file
- If there is, then I should create a separate file containing the image of the person alone

Can someone help?

Comment: That's a tall order. What do you understand with "real image"? Isn't the JPEG already a real image?

Comment: This is a very advanced topic indeed.  Have you done any research/tried anything?  There are algorithms that scanners, PDF conversion utilities use but I imagine they took hundreds or thousands of hours of combined development effort

Comment: Sounds like a "job" with need for an attached fee provided.

Comment: This is a HUGE task, which will need to be broken down into many component parts before you get any answers. Your question is essentially "send me the codes for person-recognition software please?"

Comment: "actual image" is the stopping point here. Are you talking about just stripping out all metadata in the image file so you get a final image which is just the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an existing image manipulation library like the C-based [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).